# Django generic view initial value in form

Tags: python, django, forms

i want to have default value in my form which should be current user's choice. For example, user chooses to give 5 for a movie and he should see 5 in form until he changes it.

views.py

```
class MovieDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'main/detail_movie.html'
    context_object_name = 'movie'
    form_class = RateForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MovieDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = RateForm(initial={'movie': self.object})
        context['my_rate'] = Rate.objects.filter(
                sender=self.request.user,
                movie=self.get_object()).first()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                new_rate, _ = Rate.objects.update_or_create(
                sender=self.request.user, 
                movie=self.object,
                defaults={'choice': form.cleaned_data['choice']}
            )
                return JsonResponse({'rate': model_to_dict(new_rate)}, status=200)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_movie', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

I was trying get_initial method but it still gives me '---' in form as default.

```
def get_initial(self):
        return {'choice': Rate.objects.filter(movie=self.object, sender=self.request.user).first().choice }
```

Even something like this doesn't work

```
def get_initial(self):
        return {'choice': 1 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i just had to input
`'choice': Rate.objects.filter(movie=self.object, sender=self.request.user).first().choice`
to my `context['form']` where i already had initial:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MovieDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = RateForm(
        initial={
        'movie': self.object,
        'choice': Rate.objects.filter(movie=self.object, sender=self.request.user).first().choice
        })
        context['my_rate'] = Rate.objects.filter(
                sender=self.request.user,
                movie=self.get_object()).first()
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `FormMixin` and `get_initial` method you need to use `get_form` method in `get_context_data`

```py
class MovieDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'main/detail_movie.html'
    context_object_name = 'movie'
    form_class = RateForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(MovieDetailView, self).get_initial()
        initial['movie'] = self.object # selected movie
        rate = Rate.objects.filter( # attempt to get rate
            movie=self.object,
            sender=self.request.user
        ).first()
        if rate is not None: # set rate choice only if it has been done before
            initial['choice'] = rate.choice
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MovieDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form() # use from mixin instead manual init
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                new_rate, _ = Rate.objects.update_or_create(
                sender=self.request.user, 
                movie=self.object,
                defaults={'choice': form.cleaned_data['choice']}
            )
                return JsonResponse({'rate': model_to_dict(new_rate)}, status=200)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_movie', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

Comment: Thank you, it was good tip for me to find resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your form.

form = RateForm(initial={'choice': 1})

Comment: I init it like this form = self.get_form(), I cannot do this your way...