# django - CreateView - how to insert default values with ForeignKey Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to have a model with a Foreign Key to have default dynamic values when I enter the CreateView. Let me explain:

With the following models:

```
class EquipmentType(models.Model):
    type        = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image       =models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='equipment/equipment_type')
    active      =models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects=EquipmentTypeManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('equipmentType-home')
      

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


######################################


class EquipmentItem(models.Model):
    type                        =models.ForeignKey(EquipmentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    brand                       =models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='bho some help text')
    model_type                  =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    matricola                   =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image                       =models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='equipment/equipment_item')
    libretto_uso_e_manutenzione = models.FileField(null= True, default= '', blank=True, upload_to='equipment/equipment_item/libretti_uso_e_man')
    elimina                      =models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + '. '+  self.type.type + ' - '+ self.brand + ' - ' +self.model_type

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('equipmentItem-list', kwargs={'type': self.type.type})
```

First, on the front-end, I list all the different types (chaisaws, welders etc), then by clicking on the specific type, I enter the Item-list-view:

```
class EquipmentItem_ListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = EquipmentItem
    template_name = 'equipment/equipmentItem_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'obj_list'
    ordering = ['brand'] 

    def get_queryset(self):
        type = get_object_or_404(EquipmentType, type=self.kwargs.get('type'))
        return EquipmentItem.objects.filter(type = type, elimina=False).order_by('brand')
```

Then with the following create view:

```
class EquipmentItem_CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = EquipmentItem
    template_name='equipment/equipmentItem_form.html'
    fields = ['type', 'brand', 'model_type', 'matricola', 'image', 'libretto_uso_e_manutenzione']
```

I would like the view to create a new Item with the following template:

```
{% extends 'equipment/0_base.html'%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content%}
<a class='btn btn-outline-dark mb-2' href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">&#x2190; Indietro</a>
    <div class="content-section" >
      <form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {%csrf_token%}
        <fieldset class='form-group'>
          <legend class='border-bottom mb-4'> Nuovo/modifica {{object.type.type}}</legend>

          {{ form | crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class='btn btn-outline-info' name="button"> Salva </button>
          <!-- <a href="  url 'equipmentType-home' %}" class='btn btn-outline-secondary ml-4'>Cancella</a> -->
        </div>
      </form>
    <a class='btn btn-outline-dark mt-2' href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">&#x2190; Indietro</a>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is, I would like the form to insert the type by default. Say I clicked on chainsaws, then I click on adding a new one, I would like the type of the EquipmentItem model to be already chainsaw.

for this, after searching for possible answers, I was trying to define within the EquipmentItem_CreateView a new method:

```
def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        type = get_object_or_404(EquipmentType, type=self.kwargs.get('type'))
        initial = super(EquipmentItem_CreateView, self).get_initial(**kwargs)
        initial['type'] = 'CHAINSAW'
        return initial
```

2 major problems: 1 the browser returns me the 404 err, plus CHAINSAW is hard-coded. While I would like it to be dynamic.

Hope the explanation was clear enough.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Carlo

Comment: I had similiar problem and i made it like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900395/django-generic-view-initial-value-in-form

Comment: thank you, I'm looking into it!

Comment: @bkrop one step forward: I tried with this:                                                          `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EquipmentItem_CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        print(context)

        brand= 'type context_data'
        context['form'] = EquipmentItem_Form(
            initial={
                'type': 'BANCHI SEGA',
                'brand': brand
                }
            )
        return context`

Comment: I tried some hard coded values, it works well with 'brand', but not with 'type'. strange. The problem is, compared to your case, I have a CreateView (instead of Deatail View). Which makes it a bit different I guess...

Comment: I apologize the code in the previous comment looks so horrible, I've tried some formatting...apparently not great still